Azure Function + Azure SQL Server causing data sync issues?
I have a simple C# Azure Function app running in the cloud. The function checks if an entity in our database exists, if not it creates it and returns either 200 OK or 403 Forbidden.
Initially everything runs smoothly both from a local environment connected to the Azure SQL Server and from the github deployed environment running in the cloud itself. When I delete a row from our database through Query Editor (Preview) > Table > Edit Data (Preview) > Delete Row > Save the following happens:

the locally run function communicating with the Azure SQL Server directly continues to function as expected and creates new entries
the function deployed to the cloud breaks permanently throws foreign_key errors:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_XXXs_YYYs_YYYId". The conflict occurred in database "...", table "dbo.YYYs", column 'Id'`



The function runs in Europe West. The SQL Server runs in West Germany.
The SQL Server & DB configurations are minimal with no redundancies.
I thought this indicated that there might be some covert replication happening, but when I run the function locally and the entry is created, the cloud function immediately responds with "200 OK" as well.
Like this:
namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client1 = new APIClient("http://localhost:7071/api");
            var client2 = new APIClient("cloud_url/api");
            Console.WriteLine($"VerificationResult: {client1.Verify("3f69578b-014c-4838-9ef2-aabdf79879fd")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"VerificationResult: {client2.Verify("3f69578b-014c-4838-9ef2-aabdf79879fd")}");
        }
    }
}

VerificationResult: True
VerificationResult: True

If I comment out the localhost request first the request hangs until timeout and in the Application Insights logs, I get the foreign key error.
Any ideas what might be causing this discrepancy?
I have tried restarting, redeploying and restructuring the cloud resources with different plans and region configurations
The code clearly works as it runs locally and in the cloud until a row was deleted in Query Editor (Preview)

It seems you have attempted to insert a record into the item table without a corresponding the FOREIGN KEY record table. That's the reason for getting the FOREIGN KEY error.

Check this SO thread answer for more details on FOREIGN KEY error
